# Does the present only exist to the extent that it leaves traces in the future?

Tags: ontology, time

Under what conditions can we conclude from the position that the past only exists to the extent it leaves traces in the present to the position that the present only exists to the extent it leaves traces in the future? After all, when is now?

Comment: Is this an actual position in the metaphysics of time? The way you formulated your question makes it seem as if, but I have never come across such a position. (I'm not well versed in the philosophy of time though, so that does not mean much. If you have any pointers I'd be interested...)

Comment: No. Traces in the future are not available for inspection, so they are useless as evidence. "When is now?" is of the same nature as "where is here?", it is answered by pointing, if at all.